# formatted string of series of numpy array elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, formatted-text

It seems quit trivial to me but I'm still missing an efficient and "clean" way to insert a series of element belonging to numpy array (as `aa[:,:]`) in a formatted string to be printed/written.
In fact the extended element-by-element specification syntaxes like:

```
formattedline= '%10.6f  %10.6f  %10.6f' % (aa[ii,0], aa[ii,1], aa[ii,2]) 
file1.write(formattedline+'\n')
```

are working.

But I have not found any other shorter solution, because:

```
formattedline= '%10.6f  %10.6f  %10.6f' % (float(aa[ii,:]))
file1.write(formattedline+'\n')
```

of course gives: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

or:

```
formattedline= '%10.6f  %10.6f  %10.6f' % (aa[ii,:]) 
file1.write(formattedline+'\n')
```

gives: `TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray`.
I have tried with iterators but with no success.

Of course this is interesting when there are several elements to be printed.

So: how can I combine iteration over numpy array and string formatted fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could convert it to a tuple:

```
formattedline = '%10.6f  %10.6f  %10.6f' % ( tuple(aa[ii,:]) )
```

In a more general case you could use a `join`:

```
formattedline = ' '.join('%10.6f'%F for F in aa[ii,:] )
```

Comment: that is good and working! :) ... so the second solution is actually iterating over the numpy array, very nice.

Comment: ... but still, adding one string: `formattedline= ' %4s  %10.6f  %10.6f  %10.6f' % (string1, (tuple(aa[ii,:])))` gives `TypeError: float argument required, not tuple` and I don't understand why

Comment: @gluuke you need to add them: `(string1,)+tuple(aa[ii,:])`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing the entire array to a file, use np.savetxt:

```
np.savetxt(file1, aa, fmt = '%10.6f')
```

The `fmt` parameter can be a single format, or a sequence of formats, or a multi-format string like

```
'%10.6f  %5.6f  %d'
```

Comment: ... thanks! But what about if I'm not saving the whole array at the same time? ... So if I'm adding slices of array combined with some text?

Comment: Then I think @hayden's suggestion is best. Under the hood, `np.savetxt` calls `fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))`. (In Python2, `asbytes = str`.)